# Why is Border bottom appearing even when not applied?

Tags: html, css, border

I've set a grid with 4 blocks using the floats. And on the grid items, I've applied `border-top` on every item and border-right on the odd number of items.

But for some reason, there is some kind of border on the bottom of the odd blocks.

Any reasons for this behaviour and any fixes for the same?

Extra note: This issue is not appearing when I set the grid using flexbox.

Codepen Link: https://codepen.io/vikrantnegi007/full/NXKjOb/

```css
.main-container6 {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.services-container {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  position: relative;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
}

.services-text-left {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: rgba(109, 109, 109, .75);
  -webkit-transition: all .35s;
  transition: all .35s;
  z-index: 99;
  width: 100%;
}

.services-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.services-text-in {
  padding: 60px;
}

.services-container:nth-child(2n+1) {
  border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section class="main-container6">
  <div class="services-container">
    <img alt="web-development" class="img-gray-scale" src="https://picsum.photos/1000
">
    <div class="services-text-left bg-color">
      <div class="services-text-in">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-container">
    <img alt="web-development" class="img-gray-scale" src="https://picsum.photos/1000
">
    <div class="services-text-left bg-color">
      <div class="services-text-in">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-container">
    <img alt="web-development" class="img-gray-scale" src="https://picsum.photos/1000
">
    <div class="services-text-left bg-color">
      <div class="services-text-in">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="services-container">
    <img alt="web-development" class="img-gray-scale" src="https://picsum.photos/1000
">
    <div class="services-text-left bg-color">
      <div class="services-text-in">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
          <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: _This issue is not appearing when I set the grid using flexbox._ Then why doing it with floats?

Comment: older browsers ie < 10. But the main reasons is that I'm curious as I've been using floats for quite long and never came to this kind of issue.

Comment: It's because of `border-right`. It affects the width of the image, which affects the height... if you add a right border to all items you can see the heights match up --> https://codepen.io/sol_b/full/rpBwaZ/

Comment: I knew this was coming, the point is stop supporting IE else it will go on ... no one knows how long, all IE supporters are a part of the problem, it's IE who should adapt. And forget about floats in general, only use them with the img / text relation.

Comment: @sol great. Got it so width gets change and then browser adjusts the height accordingly. please posts your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @VXp Agreed. I always suggest my colleagues to use flexbox instead of floats as they make life so much easier.

Comment: Dont use border-right, it shrinks your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using `box-sizing: border-box`...adding `border-right` affects the width of the image, which in turn affects the height.

If you add `border-right` to all items then the heights match up, and the divs align.

[demo on codepen](https://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/rpBwaZ)

Answer (score 1):

this effect occurs because the odd conatainers i.e (2n+1) has borders and even container i.e (2n) has no border, you can use padding instead to solve this. or give border to every container

```
.services-container {
    border-right: 2px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add this css properties to .services-container class,

```
.services-container {border-right: 2px solid transparent;}
```